# Mapping ADAL Sample for Ruby Sinatra to Active Directory

Tags: ruby, sinatra, adal

I am trying to run the Sinatra sample app given in the Azure Active Directory Library for Ruby: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby.   The sample is here:   https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby/tree/dev/samples/authorization_code_example

The provided README.md file tells me that I need to do this:

1. Register a web application under your Azure Active Directory account.
2. Replace `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET` and `TENANT` with your values.

My problem is that it is not clear how to map any 3 of these values to the various fields available for the Web App that I have setup in Active Directory.

- I am guessing that `TENANT` maps to a URL that will point my app to our ActiveDirectory configuration.
- I am guessing that `CLIENT_ID` maps to the application id of my web app
- I am very unsure about the `CLIENT_SECRET`

I am looking for clarity on these three fields and anything else I need to do to make this sample work.

Comment: I ended up using OAuth2.0 from scratch using this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow
And not using the ADAL library for Ruby at all.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

CLIENT_ID is the Application ID shown in the settings of the AD App Registration for the configured Web app.

CLIENT_SECRET is a password value a password set in the 'Keys' section of the Web app details.

TENANT should be a registered domain name for the AD tenant.
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#TenantIdentifier

Comment: Note that the sample doesn't completely work well.  The graph API call at line 78 is out of date.

Comment: What should the Reply URL be for this sample? I keep getting the error "The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application"

Comment: @Colbs  It just matters that the Reply URL is identical to the Reply URL configured in your App Registration on the Azure AD portal.